# Waiting for event to finish

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, webclient

Im trying to convert the response from the webclient to Json, but it's trying to create the JSON object before it is done downloaing it from the server.
Is there a "nice" way to for me to wait for WebOpenReadCompleted to be executed?

Have to mention that this is a WP7 app, so everything is Async

```
public class Client
{

    public String _url;
    private String _response;
    private WebClient _web;

    private JObject jsonsobject;
    private Boolean blockingCall;


    private Client(String url)
    {
        _web = new WebClient();
        _url = url;
    }

    public JObject Login(String username, String password)
    {
        String uriUsername = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username);
        String uriPassword = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password);

        Connect(_url + "/data.php?req=Login&username=" + uriUsername + "&password=" + uriPassword + "");
        jsonsobject = new JObject(_response); 
        return jsonsobject;
    }

    public JObject GetUserInfo()
    {

        Connect(_url + "/data.php?req=GetUserInfo");
        jsonsobject = new JObject(_response); 
        return jsonsobject;
    }

    public JObject Logout()
    {

        Connect(_url + "/data.php?req=Logout");
        jsonsobject = new JObject(_response); 
        return jsonsobject;
    }

    private void Connect(String url)
    {

        _web.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
        _web.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(WebOpenReadCompleted);
        _web.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    private void WebOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Error.Message);
            _response = "";
        } 
        else
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                _response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `EventWaitHandle` to nicely block until the async read is complete. I had a similar requirement for downloading files with `WebClient`.  My solution was to subclass `WebClient`. Full source is below. Specifically, `DownloadFileWithEvents` blocks nicely until the async download completes.

It should be pretty straightforward to modify the class for your purpose.

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient, IDisposable
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public int TimeUntilFirstByte { get; set; }
    public int TimeBetweenProgressChanges { get; set; }

    public long PreviousBytesReceived { get; private set; }
    public long BytesNotNotified { get; private set; }

    public string Error { get; private set; }
    public bool HasError { get { return Error != null; } }

    private bool firstByteReceived = false;
    private bool success = true;
    private bool cancelDueToError = false;

    private EventWaitHandle asyncWait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private Timer abortTimer = null;

    const long ONE_MB = 1024 * 1024;

    public delegate void PerMbHandler(long totalMb);

    public event PerMbHandler NotifyMegabyteIncrement;

    public MyWebClient(int timeout = 60000, int timeUntilFirstByte = 30000, int timeBetweenProgressChanges = 15000)
    {
        this.Timeout = timeout;
        this.TimeUntilFirstByte = timeUntilFirstByte;
        this.TimeBetweenProgressChanges = timeBetweenProgressChanges;

        this.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(MyWebClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
        this.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(MyWebClient_DownloadProgressChanged);

        abortTimer = new Timer(AbortDownload, null, TimeUntilFirstByte, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    protected void OnNotifyMegabyteIncrement(long totalMb)
    {
        if (NotifyMegabyteIncrement != null) NotifyMegabyteIncrement(totalMb);
    }

    void AbortDownload(object state)
    {
        cancelDueToError = true;
        this.CancelAsync();
        success = false;
        Error = firstByteReceived ? "Download aborted due to >" + TimeBetweenProgressChanges + "ms between progress change updates." : "No data was received in " + TimeUntilFirstByte + "ms";
        asyncWait.Set();
    }

    void MyWebClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cancelDueToError) return;

        long additionalBytesReceived = e.BytesReceived - PreviousBytesReceived;
        PreviousBytesReceived = e.BytesReceived;
        BytesNotNotified += additionalBytesReceived;

        if (BytesNotNotified > ONE_MB)
        {
            OnNotifyMegabyteIncrement(e.BytesReceived);
            BytesNotNotified = 0;
        }
        firstByteReceived = true;
        abortTimer.Change(TimeBetweenProgressChanges, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public bool DownloadFileWithEvents(string url, string outputPath)
    {
        asyncWait.Reset();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        this.DownloadFileAsync(uri, outputPath);
        asyncWait.WaitOne();

        return success;
    }

    void MyWebClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cancelDueToError) return;
        asyncWait.Set();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {            
        var result = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        result.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        return result;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        if (asyncWait != null) asyncWait.Dispose();
        if (abortTimer != null) abortTimer.Dispose();

        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using OpenReadAsync(). This is an asynchronous method, meaning that the calling thread is not suspended while the handler is executing.
This means your assignment operation setting jsonsobject happens while WebOpenReadCompleted() is still executing.
I'd say your best bet is to replace OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url)) with OpenRead(new Uri(url)) in your Connect(string url) method.
OpenRead() is a synchronous operation, so the calling method will wait until the WebOpenReadCompleted() method is complete before your assignment occurs in the Connect() method.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's a WP7 app so there are no synchronous operation for webclient, sorry about that

Comment: Fair enough... Then yeah, the other post showing the use of EventWaitHandle is the way to go